# Extend the Collection with Generic Types

Tags: c#, .net

My goal is to extend the Collection object to support to flag when an item is added, updated or removed from the Collection. The [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) provides an example (Example 2) of extending for a specific type. I would like to keep it Generic so I don't have to implemnent a new Class for every Collection I have.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class ChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public readonly T ChangedItem;
    public readonly T ReplacedWith;
    public readonly ChangeType ChangeType;

    public ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType change, T item, T replacement)
    {
        ChangeType = change;
        ChangedItem = item;
        ReplacedWith = replacement;
    }
}

public enum ChangeType
{
    Added,
    Removed,
    Replaced,
    Cleared
};

class CollectionChangeTracked<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;

    protected override void InsertItem<TParam>(int index, TParam newItem)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Added, newItem, null));
        }
    }

    protected override void SetItem<TParam>(int index, TParam newItem)
    {
        string replaced = Items[index];
        base.SetItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType.Replaced, replaced, newItem));
        }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem<TParam>(int index)
    {
        TParam removedItem = Items[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Removed, removedItem, null));
        }
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType.Cleared, null, null));
        }
    }
}
```

Question:
I'm receiving an error on the line: base.InsertItem(index, newItem) 
It says I have invalid arguments but nothing more. Same issue in SetItem and RemoveItem.

Updated code that compiles:

```
public class ChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public readonly T ChangedItem;
    public readonly T? ReplacedWith;
    public readonly ChangeType ChangeType;

    public ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType change, T item, T? replacement)
    {
        ChangeType = change;
        ChangedItem = item;
        ReplacedWith = replacement;
    }
}

public enum ChangeType
{
    Added,
    Removed,
    Replaced,
    Cleared
};

class CollectionChangeTracked<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T newItem)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Added, newItem, default(T)));
    }


    protected override void SetItem(int index, T newItem)
    {
        T replaced = Items[index];
        base.SetItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Replaced, replaced, newItem));
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        T removedItem = Items[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Removed, removedItem, null));
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;

        if (temp != null)
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Cleared, null, null));
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: What's the problem? What do you want to achieve when the event is triggered? What do you want the event to communicate?

Comment: Surely `TParam` is irrelevant on all those methods - ist the type being added/removed/etc `T`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using something `ObservableCollection<T>` or `BindingList<T>`, both of which provide change notification? Unless this is an exercise in generic programming, either of those is probably a better choice than rolling your own.

Comment: @Oded, looks like I lost the question when I copied in the code. I've added it back.

Comment: @Jamiec, I'm receiving compile errors.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, I looked at ObservableCollection<T>, it requires all the consumers to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. As far as BindList, I originally had it as a List but FXCop said that since this is a public property in Class Library that I should use a Collection instead.

Comment: @Josh: `ObservableCollection<T>` has no such restriction; what makes you say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@daveL is totally right, what you want is a generic event args:

```
public class ChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public readonly T ChangedItem;
    public readonly T ReplacedWith;
    public readonly ChangeType ChangeType;

    public ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType change, T item, T replacement)
    {
        ChangeType = change;
        ChangedItem = item;
        ReplacedWith = replacement;
    }
}
```

But what he has missed in his answer is how to use it; first make your event handler use the same type `T` as the main class:

```
class CollectionChangeTracked<T> : Collection<T>
{
    public event EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;

   ....

}
```

Then, your individual methods, rather than redefining the type as `TParam` should be using the `T` defined at class level:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T newItem)
{
    base.InsertItem(index, newItem);
    EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
    if (temp != null)
    {
      // Added <T> after ChangedEventArgs  
      temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(ChangeType.Added, newItem, default(T)));
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/XFCLN26271

Comment: Ah yeah but in the absence of the actual question I wasn't going to spell it out.. You could have edited my answer if you were that bothered

Comment: @daveL - Ah, but I kinda like spelling it out - thats kind of the point of a Q&A site :D

Comment: @Jamie... Questions are needed for a Q&A site. Otherwise it's a load of people randomly posting stuff.

Comment: Just wont compile, because you cant pass null to the ChangedEventArgs constructor (change and replacement) because T is not a nullable type.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders - yup, I changed that to `default(T)` in the live example, just forgot to edit it back in here, I actually prefer your solution of making it `T?` though

Comment: @Jamiec, Thank you, glad you took the extra and guessed at the missing question!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this would be a help but I'm guessing a bit as your question is vague and unfinished

```
 public class ChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly T ChangedItem;
        public readonly T ReplacedWith;
        public readonly ChangeType ChangeType;

        public ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType change, T item, T replacement)
        {
            ChangeType = change;
            ChangedItem = item;
            ReplacedWith = replacement;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your suggestions make sense. I've updated the question to include your modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You have to difine ChangedEventArgs class as Generic.

Try this:

```
public class ChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public readonly T ChangedItem;
    public readonly ChangeType ChangeType;
    public readonly T ReplacedWith;

    public ChangedEventArgs(ChangeType change, T item,
        T replacement)
    {
        ChangeType = change;
        ChangedItem = item;
        ReplacedWith = replacement;
    }
}

public enum ChangeType
{
    Added,
    Removed,
    Replaced,
    Cleared
};

class CollectionChangeTracked<T> : Collection<T> 
{
    public event EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> Changed;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T newItem)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(
                ChangeType.Added, newItem, default(T)));
        }
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T newItem)
    {
        T replaced = Items[index];
        base.SetItem(index, newItem);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(
                ChangeType.Replaced, replaced, newItem));
        }
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        T removedItem = Items[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(
                ChangeType.Removed, removedItem, default(T)));
        }
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        base.ClearItems();

        EventHandler<ChangedEventArgs<T>> temp = Changed;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new ChangedEventArgs<T>(
                ChangeType.Cleared, default(T), default(T)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is only generic for structs... not much use as far as I can see

Comment: Both the ChangedItem and the ReplacedWith fields must be nullable, so they can fit the Removed and Added event. So it has to be structs.

Comment: No this would need to be generic for both value and reference types. Otherwise it's useless in my opinion.